# Why is this python selenium example not working?

Tags: python, selenium

I recently needed selenium to do something with a website. So I did some research and found this guide on how to set up selenium with an example: https://dzone.com/articles/python-getting-started

They provided the following example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')
```

But instead of working it throws an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Why is this example code not working?
Thanks, Ira.

Comment: can you try restarting your laptop ? sometimes if you call selenium too many times the process still runs in the background. Maybe just try refreshing your kernel or restarting your machine will help. I faced this similar issue.

Comment: I did try that rebooting did not help sadly.

Comment: How did you install the selenium ?

Answer (score 0):

Run following commands and then try again

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
sudo pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

and change your code like below

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

if none of these worked, try to set geckodriver path for firefox like this

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver', options=options)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! I did run the following commands. But I still gets the same results. Still the same error provided in the question.

Comment: edited my answer added 4 lines . check if it works for you

Comment: browser and display are not defined. And print has to be print()

Comment: that is because you are using python3 . check it with Chrome instead of Firefox

Comment: Now its saying `The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.`

Comment: check answer, added new lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194074/discussion-between-ira-kloostra-nathan-and-siyavash-vaez-afshar).